# Whatsapp Unicode Phishing Link

Tags: phishing, whatsapp, unicode

I have been receiving messages from relatives that goes like this:

> AirAsia is rewarding everyone with 2 free plane tickets to celebrate 24 Years of quality service. Get your free ticket at: [http://airasîa.com/free-tickets/](http://airas%C3%AEa.com/free-tickets/)  .

which is a unicode link to http://xn--airasa-fwa.com/free-tickets/

I am just really curious how a click on this link on phone could allow hackers to hijack my friends and relatives Whatsapp accounts? Trying to access this site on PC gives me a 404 error.

In the mean time I have asked those who sent me this message to use Whatsapp settings to log out from all computer sessions.  Is that enough?

---

**Update 1:**

I traced the phishing link to http://com-cupons.com/aa/, which uses js to redirect to http://aldi-com-2018.com/aa/.  This is the URL containing the actual contents my friends were looking at.

There was a link like this:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=*AirAsia is rewarding everyone with 2 free plane tickets* to celebrate 24 Years of quality service. Get your free ticket at : http://airasîa.com/free-tickets/  .">
```

So I suppose that's why I am receiving those messages.

But I still can't figure out the intent of this phishing.  Maybe it has something to do with this?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
  var foxscript = document.createElement('script');
  foxscript.src = '//js.foxpush.com/aldi-com-2018com.js?v='+Math.random();
  foxscript.type = 'text/javascript';
  foxscript.async = 'true';
  var fox_s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  fox_s.parentNode.insertBefore(foxscript, fox_s);})();
  </script>
      <body oncontextmenu="return false">
          <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
          <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-91015564-3"></script>
          <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-91015564-3');
  </script>
```

What does it actually do?

---

**Update 2:**

Found out the phishing site actually tries to redirect users to `final.html` under the same `aldi-com-2018` domain. The site contains obfuscated javascript that I have no idea how to decipher, but it does contain this piece of code:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="//go.onclasrv.com/apu.php?zoneid=956139" async onerror="_tyzjj()" onloaded="_rxnhqlpp()"></script>
```

Google search on **onclasrv** returns bunch of adware related results. I'm guessing that is the final intention then?

Comment: Analysing random malware or code on random sites is off-topic here. You can imagine that we would be flooded with a lot of code.